# debugging trigger.io app with catalyst seems to only connect once

Tags: trigger.io

I've been working on the weather app demo for trigger.io using the android emulator with windows 7. I've run into an issue where, after running it once it will no longer connect to Catalyst. I've tried refreshing the https://trigger.io/catalyst/ page for a new ID, rebuilding and re-running and it works sometimes but not always. Under clients I'll see 127.0.0.1 once in bold and one more more instances below it not in bold but the Targets list is empty. Any suggestions?

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://trigger.io/catalyst/target/target-script-min.js#BE2EEEE8-3796-4249-8C00-04CE67A969FD"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mustache.js"></script>       
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/weather.js"></script>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="x-mustache-template" id="forecast_information_tmpl">
            <h1>Forecast for {{display_location.full}}</h1>
            <p>{{observation_time}}</p>
        </script>

        <script type="x-mustache-template" id="current_conditions_tmpl">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="{{icon_url}}" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <div>{{weather}}</div>
                        <div>{{temp_f}}&deg;F</div>
                        <div>Humidity: {{relative_humidity}}</div>
                        <div>Wind: {{wind_string}}</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </script>

        <script type="x-mustache-template" id="forecast_conditions_tmpl">
            {{#forecastday}}
            <td>
                <h2>{{date.weekday_short}}</h2>
                <img src="{{icon_url}}">
                <div>{{conditions}}</div>
                <div>Low: {{low.fahrenheit}}&deg;F</div>
                <div>High: {{high.fahrenheit}}&deg;F</div>
            </td>
            {{/forecastday}}
        </script>

        <header id="forecast_information"></header>

        <section id="current_conditions"></section>

        <section id="forecast_conditions">
            <table>
                <tr>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </section>



   </body>
</html>
```

weather.js

```
window.forge.enableDebug();

var weather = {
    "current_observation": {
        "display_location": {
            "full": "San Francisco, CA"
        },
        "observation_time":"Last Updated on September 20, 3:50 AM PDT",
        "weather": "Mostly Cloudy",
        "temp_f": 54.4,
        "temp_c": 12.4,
        "relative_humidity":"89%",
        "wind_string":"From the WNW at 4.0 MPH",
        "icon_url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_mostlycloudy.gif"
    },
    "forecast": {
        "simpleforecast": {
            "forecastday": [
                { "date": { "weekday_short": "Thu" },
                  "period": 1,
                  "high": { "fahrenheit": "64", "celsius": "18" },
                  "low": { "fahrenheit": "54", "celsius": "12" },
                  "conditions": "Partly Cloudy",
                  "icon_url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif" },
                { "date": { "weekday_short": "Fri" },
                  "period": 2,
                  "high": { "fahrenheit": "70", "celsius": "21" },
                  "low": { "fahrenheit": "54", "celsius": "12" },
                  "conditions": "Mostly Cloudy",
                  "icon_url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/mostlycloudy.gif" },
                { "date": { "weekday_short": "Sat" },
                  "period": 3,
                  "high": { "fahrenheit": "70", "celsius": "21" },
                  "low": { "fahrenheit": "52", "celsius": "11" },
                  "conditions": "Partly Cloudy",
                  "icon_url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif" }
            ]
        }
    }
};

forge.logging.info(JSON.stringify(weather));


function populateWeatherConditions (weather) {
    var tmpl, output;
    forge.logging.log("[populateWeatherConditions] beginning populating weather conditions");

    tmpl = $("#forecast_information_tmpl").html();
    output = Mustache.to_html(tmpl, weather.current_observation);
    $("#forecast_information").append(output);
    forge.logging.log("[populateWeatherConditions] finished populating forecast information");

    tmpl = $("#current_conditions_tmpl").html();
    output = Mustache.to_html(tmpl, weather.current_observation);
    $("#current_conditions").append(output);
    forge.logging.log("[populateWeatherConditions] finished populating current conditions");

    tmpl = $("#forecast_conditions_tmpl").html();
    output = Mustache.to_html(tmpl, weather.forecast.simpleforecast);
    $("#forecast_conditions table tr").append(output);
    forge.logging.log("[populateWeatherConditions] finished populating forecast conditions");

    forge.logging.log("[populateWeatherConditions] finished populating weather conditions");
};

$(function () {
    populateWeatherConditions(weather);
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does your app wait when you start it up? The call to forge.enableDebug() should pause the app until a connection to Catalyst is established...

Comment: James - thanks for the reply. I just tried it again since it had been a few days and it connected correctly. Maybe it was just an intermittent problem?

Comment: Thanks James Brady - it was not clear from the docs that enableDebug() also has the side effect of pausing the app until the debugger is connected.